# Trying to create a formula field in Salesforce to calculate the average number of days

Tags: salesforce

Trying to create a formula field in salesforce to calculate the average number of days taken from Close date to (either of the 2 other dates).
E.g

Close date
Email start date
live date

formula I'm trying to write is close date - (earliest of the email start date or the live date).

Help will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `MAX()` function available but it accepts only numbers, not dates. So have a look at these and pick whichever you're feeling more comfortable with ;)

(Formula type must be of type Number, call it "Lifespan (in days)" or something)

```
IF(Email_Start_Date__c > Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c) - Close_Date__c
```

or

```
MAX(Email_Start_Date__c - Close_Date__c, Live_Date__c - Close_Date__c)
```

---

Edit to incorporate Priyanka's problem from the comments:
If you have several dates you want to fall back on (if one is null, try another one) it's best to use `BLANKVALUE` function to avoid long chains of IF statements:

```
BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, 
    BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, 
        BLANKVALUE(Live_Date__c, 
            BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c)
        )
    )
)
```

You can also combine it with the trick with IF's to select lowest one, for example:

```
BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, 
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Go_Live_Date__c)), 
        IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Go_Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c , Go_Live_Date__c ),
        BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c)
    )
)
```

This will check the override date first. If it's null but **both** email start & go live dates are set - will select smaller of the 2. If any of them is blank - will keep falling back to check estimated dates and finally will give up if with null if everything was null.

But I have to say if you really need to write such convoluted things - you're doing something wrong. Force your users to start filling in some dates earlier, it's a sign of very poor data quality...

Comment: Thank you, I tried creating this, however, it's working well for records which has the 'live date' populated or both live date and email start date populated but it doesn't seem to work for the ones which only have an email start date (in which case it should work out email start date - close date).

Comment: Just add ISBLANK() checks as you need then, for example `IF(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c) || Email_Start_Date__c > Live_Date__c, ...` ("||" is a boolean "or" condition). Full functions reference: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm

Comment: You're a star! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hi again, is there a way to calculate the earliest of two (or more) dates (other date fields) via a formula field?

Comment: Have you played with the first snippet at all :D Should be as simple as `IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c)`

Comment: trying to create a rev date field  (formula field) I want to add conditions within this formula where it calculates the earliest of two dates .. not sure if it is possible.

Comment: IF( 
NOT(ISBLANK(Over_ride_Date__c)), 
Over_ride_Date__c, 
IF( 
AND( 
ISBLANK(Over_ride_Date__c), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c)) 
), 
Email_Start_Date__c, 
IF( 
AND( 
ISBLANK(Over_ride_Date__c), 
ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c), 
NOT(ISBLANK( Live_Date__c )) 
), 
Live_Date__c , 
IF( 
AND( 
ISBLANK(Over_ride_Date__c), 
ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c), 
ISBLANK( Live_Date__c ), 
NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c )) 
), 
Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ,

Comment: IF(AND( 
ISBLANK(Over_ride_Date__c), 
ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c), 
ISBLANK( Live_Date__c ), 
ISBLANK( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ), 
NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c )) 
), 
Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c , 
null 
)))))

Comment: Oh my... ok, for a start you can simplify this abomination to this:
BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Live_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c)))). Once you verify it works the same and you're happy with it, start experimenting with IFs. Lower of which dates you want to pick? And maybe we should go to a chat session?

Comment: thanks so much, let me give this a try! I don't think I have enough reputation to initiate a chat :0

Comment: I see, same with Salesforce-dedicated site :/ Pity, even if I'd upvote all your questions it wouldn't be enough (it gives +2 only).

Comment: Probably asking the obvious but how do I include the 'IF' function within the BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Live_Date__c, BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c))))...eg. i want to include this IF( Email_Start_Date__c  <  Go_Live_Date__c ,  Email_Start_Date__c ,  Go_Live_Date__c )

Comment: hi again... what am I missing here... it gives me an error that i'm missing a closing bracket!   BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, 
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c)), 
        IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c , Live_Date__c ),
        BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c,
     IF(NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c )) && NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c )),
  IF( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c <  Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c ,  Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ,  Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c ))
    )
)

Comment: the formula works well until I add the function to check if both estimated email start date and est. go live dates are not blank, take the lowest of the two.

Comment: made a few more tweaks to the logic.. can't figure out the missing bracket ')' :o.. BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c, 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c)), 
IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c , Live_Date__c ), 
IF(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Live_Date__c), 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_G_L_Date__c )),
IF( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c <  Estimated_G_L_Date__c )),
IF(ISBLANK( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ) && ISBLANK( Estimated_G_L_Date__c ),
BLANKVALUE(  Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c )
))

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense now :D last part for example, `BLANKVALUE( Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c )` - where's the second parameter (what to do if the value is blank). Or the fact that first you compare `Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c < Estimated_G_L_Date__c` and later you check if they're null - should probably be other way around because if they actually can be compared it means they're never null :D Either edit the question or make new one with clear list of fields you have and what logic you want to implement. "If this value is empty, I want to take smaller out of this and that..." style

Comment: This is actually getting way too confusing and long :o  , estimated go live date is actually a formula field which will always have a value so I did not add the second parameter. I'm going to post a new question with the login. thanks!!!

Comment: I've added a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357956/trying-to-create-a-custom-revenue-date-field-in-salesforce