# Trying to create a custom 'Revenue Date' field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to create a '**Revenue Date**' field which follows the logic below.. 
I want the revenue date field to calculate based on the date fields which our CS team edits.
The fields (editable date fields) are
-   Over ride date 
-   Email start date
-   live date
-   estimated email start date
-   estimated G L date

A 5th auto calculated date field (**Estimated Go Live Date**) which **always has a date value** (to be used only if the above fields are blank)

So, the logic I’m trying to use is

(i) Is there an **over-ride date**? If yes, then take this and stop. **If no**, go on to (ii)

(ii)Is there at least one of ‘**Email Start Date**’ or ‘**Live Date**’? If yes, take the earlier of these and stop. **If no**, go on to (iii)

(iii)               Is there at least one of ‘**estimated Email Start Date**’ and the ‘**estimated G L Date**’? ? If yes, take the earlier of these and stop. **If no**, go on to (iv)

(iv)     if all the above fields are blank, take the **Estimated Go Live Date**

I know this looks confusing but its only because the way we calculate our revenue which depends on the dates entered by our CS team of when we are live on the clients site (not the same as the close date of the deal)..

Seem to have gone wrong somewhere in this formula below..

BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c,
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c)), IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c , Live_Date__c )), IF(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Live_Date__c)),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK( Estimated_G_L_Date__c )),
 IF( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c < Estimated_G_L_Date__c,  Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ,  Estimated_G_L_Date__c  )),
     IF(ISBLANK( Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c ) && ISBLANK( Estimated_G_L_Date__c )),BLANKVALUE( Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c,  Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c  )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to walk you through my design process ;)

The basic shape of formula could be something like this:

```
BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c,
    IF(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Live_Date__c),
        IF(ISBLANK(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Estimated_G_L_Date__c),
            Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c,
            /* need to use Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c or Estimated_G_L_Date__c */
        ),
        /* need to use Email_Start_Date__c or Live_Date__c */
    )
)
```

Should be easy for now. if "Override" is not set and both "Email Start date" and "Live date" are blank - go to next variables. Else (which is the part we don't have yet) if at least one of them is set - we'll try to use them. And similar with the last pair of dates.

---

So now what would it be:

1. Email and Live are filled in - take smaller
2. Email filled in, Live null - take Email
3. Email null, Live filled - take Live

There are several ways to do it. Bit long but readable:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c),
    Live_Date__c,
    IF(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c),
        Email_Start_Date__c,
        IF(Email_Start_Date__c < Live_Date__c, Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c)
    )
)
```

But I'm going to advocate this:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c) || BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c) < Live_Date__c,
    BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c),
    Live_Date__c
)
```

And here's the proof it works:

[image: truth table]

(9 rows only because that's all combinations: `smaller/bigger/null` * `smaller/bigger/null`). And in fact last one (`null and null`) we've ruled out with previous IF statement.

---

**And this leads us to...**

```
BLANKVALUE(Over_ride_Date__c,
    IF(ISBLANK(Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Live_Date__c),
        IF(ISBLANK(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Estimated_G_L_Date__c),
            Estimated_Go_Live_Date__c,
            IF(ISBLANK(Estimated_G_L_Date__c) || BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_G_L_Date__c) < Estimated_G_L_Date__c,
                BLANKVALUE(Estimated_Email_Start_Date__c, Estimated_G_L_Date__c),
                Estimated_G_L_Date__c
            )
        ),
        IF(ISBLANK(Live_Date__c) || BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c) < Live_Date__c,
            BLANKVALUE(Email_Start_Date__c, Live_Date__c),
            Live_Date__c
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can I say the obvious, you are a Salesforce genius! It works just perfectly and you've explained it so well. Thanks so much for the effort and help.  I must take SF lessons from you :)

Comment: Glad you like it and that it works OK ;) It sure beats the orgy of comments we've made in the previous one...

Comment: @eyescream I'm surprised on the high quality of yours answers. I'm your fan :)

Comment: Hi @MartinBorthiry! Thank you very much for these kind words but I confess this one is an well-placed investment. Priyanka's issue is a bit of nemesis for me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584952/trying-to-create-a-formula-field-in-salesforce-to-calculate-the-average-number-o), I've decided it's better to spend extra time to document this answer & "teach" vs have the "new comment" notifications pop up for next 2 months :P